# I want to add text to a background like this as show in the image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-imageview

I have source image and a background image.
When i add the text in the layout, it is getting displayed behind the image.
So user can't able to see it.
So I need to display text above the image as in the "YouTube".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOPE THIS CODE WILL HELP YOU OUT. You can draw text above the image and set as the backgound of the image view.

```
    //originalBitmap is a bitmap made from your image


    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(originalBitmap);

    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); // Text Color
    paint.setStrokeWidth(12); // Text Size
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)); 

    // Text Overlapping Pattern
    canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    canvas.drawText("Testing...", 10, 10, paint);

    yourimageview.setImagebitmap(originalBitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you define textview after imageviews in your framelayout xml, or you can bring the text view to front:

```
textView.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FrameLayout` with text as first Child